# MySQL - Total of parent + child categories

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I have two tables:

parent-child 'categories':

```
id    name         parent_id
1     Food         NULL
2     Pizza        1
3     Pasta        2
```

'transactions':

```
id     amount      category_id
1      100         1
2      50          2
3      25          2
```

I want to return all the Categories along with two total columns:

**total** = The sum of the amount for all transactions with this category_id

**parentTotal** = total + the total of all its child categories

Example (using the tables above):

```
id    name         parent_id    total    parentTotal
1     Food         NULL         100      175
2     Pizza        1            0        0
3     Pasta        2            75       0
```

EDIT:

Code updated (based on code from Nedret Recep below) and works fine...

```
SELECT 
    tmp1.id, tmp1.name, tmp1.parent_id, tmp1.total, IFNULL(tmp1.total, 0) + IFNULL(tmp2.s, 0)  AS parenttotal
   FROM
        (SELECT
                ca.id, ca.name, ca.parent_id, SUM(tr.amount) as total
        FROM
            categories ca

        LEFT JOIN
                transactions tr
        ON
                tr.category_id = ca.id 
        GROUP BY
                ca.id)
    AS tmp1     

LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT
            c.id, c.parent_id as categoryid, SUM(t.amount) AS s  
        FROM
            transactions t
        RIGHT JOIN
            categories c
        ON
            t.category_id = c.id
        GROUP BY 
            c.parent_id)
    AS tmp2

ON tmp2.categoryid = tmp1.id 

order by coalesce(tmp1.parent_id, tmp1.id), tmp1.parent_id
```

I'd really appreciate some help - thanks!

Comment: Are the categories only on 2 levels or it it is tree-like structure with unlimited depth? I.e. could category Pizza have sub-categories too. There would be different approaches with 2-level only and unlimited levels tree.

Comment: Yep, categories are only two levels deep. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one inner join we calculate the totals in category which is standard. Then with another inner join we calculate the sums but this time grouping by parent_id. Then we join the two result tables to have both sums in one row. This query will be slow with large tables so an alternative approach on application level would do better.

```
  SELECT 
        tmp1.id, tmp1.name, tmp1.parent_id, tmp1.total, tmp1.total + tmp2.s AS parenttotal
   FROM
   (SELECT
        ca.id, ca.name, ca.parent_id, SUM(tr.amount) as total
   FROM
        transactions tr
   INNER JOIN
        categories ca
   ON
        tr.categoru_id = ca.id 
   GROUP BY
        ca.id)AS tmp1     
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (
   SELECT
     c.parent_id as categoryid, SUM(t.amount) AS s  
   FROM
      transactions t
   INNER JOIN
      categories c
   ON
      t.category_id = c.i
   GROUP 
       BY c.id ) AS tmp2
   ON
       tmp2.categoryid = tmp.id
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I changed my answer above with an updated version of my code - based on yours. It all works fine. However, if a parent category has no transactions, both the total and the parent total return zero - i.e. it doesn't add up the totals for the child transactions. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `tmp1.total + tmp2.s` with `IFNULL(tmp1.total, 0) + tmp2.s`

IFNULL is useful to convert NULL to 0 and keep the value otherwise.

Comment: @ginsberg: Actually you may need to apply `IFNULL()` to `tmp2.s` too.

Comment: Thank you both for this. Works great now. Code above updated.